# How to give separate values to table items for right clicking in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a server sided application in electron. The server side is the GUI and I'm using Electron as the front-end. When a client connects to the server, I have a table that shows the connected clients. So for every client, it automatically displays the information in a table like it's name, IP, country etc. What I want to do, is set the value of that table row equal to a socket. So when I right click that table row, it gives me options for that client.

This is how I made the table:

```
            <table id="connections" width=100%>
                <tr id="headi">
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>IP</th>
                    <th>Country</th>
                    <th>Connected Since</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Ricky</td>
                    <td>192.167.87.1</td>
                    <td>Noobsville</td>
                    <td>Never</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
</section>
```

I still haven't done the automatic adding of clients but this is what this will look like. Please do let me know if there is a way to assign a socket to a row. Or I'm just doing it all wrong and that's not how it's done.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are many ways to go about doing this, but basically you're trying to display some data in a table, then display a different view when something is clicked. In your case, since it doesn't seem like you have a lot of experience with JS or HTML, I'd strongly recommend looking into one of the more popular web frameworks (I'd personally recommend React.js but there are many others) and learning how to use that, I think once you get through those tutorials you should be able to see how to do what you want to do.

Comment: Ooo. Yes, it's true that I don't have much experience is JS or HTML. I'm still learning. But that's not what I want. See, think of a table that has a row for every client connected. When I right client click that row(Note that the row represents a connected client), it shows a context menu that gives me many different options among which, there is one "Close Connection" option. When I click that option, I want to Close the client that I have selected (So the row that I have selected). So here's what I want to know. Is there like a way one can assign a secret or hidden value to a row?

Comment: It's possible to assign a non-standard attribute such as `<td my-attr="some value">`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example to achieve what you need. You need to research more on how to fire API call and stuff to handle the on selection change

```js
$('.action').on('change', function() {
    const val = $(this).val()
    
    if (val == "1") {
      $(this).closest('tr').remove()   
    }
    else if (val == "3") {
      console.log("Socket ID: " + $(this).closest('tr').data('socketid'))
    }

});
```

```css
table tr td, table tr th {
   text-align: center;
   border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="connections" width=100%>
                <tr id="headi">
                    <th>Action</th>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>IP</th>
                    <th>Country</th>
                    <th>Connected Since</th>
                </tr>
                <tr data-socketid="10001">
                    <td>
                        <select class="action">
                           <option value=""></option>
                           <option value="1">Close</option>
                           <option value="2">Other Action</option>
                           <option value="3">Show Socket</option>
                       </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Ricky</td>
                    <td>192.167.87.1</td>
                    <td>Noobsville</td>
                    <td>Never</td>
                </tr>
                <tr data-socketid="10002">
                    <td>
                        <select class="action">
                           <option value=""></option>
<option value="1">Close</option>
                           <option value="2">Other Action</option>
                           <option value="3">Show Socket</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>John</td>
                    <td>192.167.87.2</td>
                    <td>Noobsville</td>
                    <td>Never</td>
                </tr>
                <tr data-socketid="10003">
                    <td>
                        <select class="action">
                           <option value=""></option>
                           <option value="1">Close</option>
                           <option value="2">Other Action</option>
                           <option value="3">Show Socket</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>Smith</td>
                    <td>192.167.87.3</td>
                    <td>Noobsville</td>
                    <td>Never</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

**Edit**

You can use data attribute to store additional data about your elements

```
<tr id="tr-test" data-xx="somevalue1"></tr>
<td id="td-test" data-yy="somevalue2"></td>
<div id="div-test" data-zz="somevalue3"></div>

// To retrieve
$('#tr-test').data('xx')
$('#td-test').data('yy')
$('#div-test').data('zz')
```

**Edit 2**

```
// To set data attribute
$('#tr-test').data('xx', 'xxx')
$('#td-test').data('yy', 'yyy')
$('#div-test').data('zz', 'zzz')
```

Comment: Thank you Jimmy. You're a saint that's also a really great idea. But what I really want to know is how do I give like a "secret or hidden value" . This hidden value will be the socket (not to worry about how to attain this value but just how to set this value and use it if already attained) like an attribute you can put this value in and retrieving it in a JavaScript file.

Comment: You can use data attribute to store additional data, see updated answer

Comment: Oooh! Thank you so very much. Also, how do you set this data from from JS (Not from html)

Comment: To set value, just pass the value as second parameter

Comment: Aaah...I would up-vote your answer but I'm less than 15 rep. Sorry but I truly appreciate it man :)
Thank You,